# Chinese national with a UK residence permit traveling back to China for a short stay

Tags: visas, uk, chinese-citizens, permits

I am asking this question on behalf of a friend and his wife. My friend holds a full UK passport and his wife (Chinese National) holds a residence permit with leave to remain granted.

My friends wife is looking to visit China for a 3 week period but is concerned that she has to travel with her husband to leave the UK and then be granted entry again? Is this true?

Is she only able to gain entry with my friend (her husband) who holds a full UK passport to validate her UK Residence Permit?

Does he need to travel out with her if he is needed for her to gain entry or could he fly out say a week before she returns home to then complete the return leg of the journey together?

Has anyone has experience with this before?

Answer (score 4):

The UK Residence is dependent on him only for its existence. Other than that it stands on its own as does her status. If it grants her entry and residency, right to work, access to some UK public services, etc..., then she can utilizes these features irrespective of who is physically present with her at the time.